# It seems that setup() is not called when the test is running

Tags: android, android-activity, android-testing

I am developing a test class for my application. The test class code looks like this:

```
   public class ProfileActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ProfileActivity> {

     ProfileActivity profileActivity;

     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     public ProfileActivityTest(Class<ProfileActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      }

     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     public ProfileActivityTest() {
        super(ProfileActivity.class);
      }
     protected void setup() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        profileActivity = getActivity();
      }
     public void test_profileActivityLoggingIn() {
        assertNotNull(profileActivity);
        assertEquals(View.GONE, profileActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnAddOrEdit).getVisibility());
      }
     protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
      }
}
```

The problem is that I get assertionFailure on  assertNotNull(profileActivity) though profileActivity is instantiated in setup(). I don't understand what I am doing wrong;

Comment: because that's `setUp`, not `setup`

Answer (score 1):

As @njzk2 has mentioned, "setup" should be changed to "setUp".